# Can a ssh key work for restricted to home user

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, openssh

I am currently running linuxmint and openssh.  I have 2 accounts on my computer Joe and Bob.  I have the keys and passphrase created by joe stored in the /home/joe/.ssh/ folder. I can connect to Joe using ssh/sftp. but I can not connect to Bob. My question is do I have to create a new set of keys for Bob in order to connect to him even though both accounts are on the same machine? Also I have tried to chroot jail for sftp users (Subsystem sftp internal-sftp) I get locked out of BOTH accounts when trying to use it. It worked when I was using a password instead of a key passphrase.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can connect to Joe using ssh/sftp. but I can not connect to Bob.

How I see it: Joe has the public key and it in an `authorized_keys` file and Bob doesn't

> My question is do I have to create a new set of keys for Bob in order to connect to him even though both accounts are on the same machine?

You can copy the public key into Bob's authorized_keys file.  Try `ssh-copy-id bob` or edit the /home/joe/.ssh/authorized_keys on Bob.

Permissions on HOME directories must deny group and "others" write for SSH keys to work since the `.ssh` directory could be renamed and re-created as directory write permission controls that.

> Also I have tried to chroot jail for sftp users (Subsystem sftp internal-sftp) I get locked out of BOTH accounts when trying to use it. It worked when I was using a password instead of a key passphrase.

You sound to me like you want to use [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) which is in APT, try `apt-get install scponly`.

Comment: Thank you so very much this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In order to log in to a user account on a remote machine using SSH, you need the public key for the account to be in the `~/.ssh` directory for the account, and you need the private key that matches the public key to be in the `~/.ssh` directory on the local machine from which you are attempting to connect.

You can use the `-i` option to `ssh` to explicitly specify another file other than the default private key file in `~/.ssh`.

You can use the same private and public key pairs for any number of users. However, the keys must match, that is the must have been created as a pair. If you lose a private key, it is not possible to recover the public key. If you loose the public key you can regenerate it from the private key using an `openssl` command.

You can put public keys for additional users who you wish to allow to log into an account in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Other than having the private key file in `~/.ssh` on the remote machine, the most common error that prevents you from logging in is file permissions. Make sure that your `~/.ssh` directory permission is no more than 700 and that the file permissions on any private keys, `id_dsa` or `id_rsa` are no more than 400.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I figured out how to use the pubkey :)